# Save Canvas As Image to phone storage Phonegap

Tags: android, canvas, cordova, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins

I have an application that uses Canvas to create custom images. I have been able to hack all of it except being able to download/save the image to the user's phone storage, I have tried using the canvas to image phonegap plugin, but it saves blank images or returns errors such as "bad base64" or "EOF file error"

this the link where I got the plug-in http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/html5-canvas-todataurl-support-for-android-devices-working-phonegap-2-2-0-plugin/

This just converts the canvas to base64 data format for all android versions from 2.2 Froyo since the earlier versions have issues with the javascript `function toDataURL()`

How can I now save the canvas as image to the user's phone

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The [Canvas2ImagePlugin.js](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) expects a proper implementation of canvas, which is not available for older Android versions (like Froyo). Just get the base64 data url using the method you've [mentioned](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/html5-canvas-todataurl-support-for-android-devices-working-phonegap-2-2-0-plugin/) and pass the value inside the Canvas2Image plugin to [imageData](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin/blob/master/www/Canvas2ImagePlugin.js#L26).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need for Android unfortunately, dyu know any plug-in, and tutorials specifically???

Comment: These are the instructions for Android. The Canvas2ImagePlugin passes to the native side a base64 encoded representation of the canvas content, which is acquired using toDataURL(). On older Android versions the toDataURL() returns garbage.

So, instead of using the toDataURL() you get the same content using the [method](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/html5-canvas-todataurl-support-for-android-devices-working-phonegap-2-2-0-plugin/).

This is not ready made but this is all it takes to combine those two plugins to get what you want.

Comment: Does Canvas2ImagePlugin give back the path where the file is saves in phones filesystem??